# How to route page in angularJS in IE Browser?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, internet-explorer

I'm currently encountering some error of routing in angularJS.

I have codes like this :

**Controller**

```
$scope.classCode = [];

   var userId = localStorageService.get('userId');
   //$scope.CurrentModule = sharedService.getCurrentModule();
    EvaluationService.getClassCode(userId).then(function (results) {
        $scope.classCode = results.data;
    });

    $scope.redirectViews = function (classCode, enrollCode, isValid) {
        if (!isValid) {
            localStorageService.set('currentClassCode', classCode);
            localStorageService.set('currentEnrollCode', enrollCode);

            //location.href = "/#/evaluate";

            $window.location.href="#/evaluate";

            //$("a[href='#/evaluate']").click();

            //$(location).attr('href', "/#/evaluate");

        }
    };
```

**App**

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when("/home", {
        controller: "homeController",
        templateUrl: "templates/home.html"
    });

    $routeProvider.when('/evaluations', {
        controller: 'EvaluationController',
        templateUrl: 'Projects/Evaluation/templates/evaluation.html'
    });
    $routeProvider.when('/evaluate', {
        controller: 'CriteriaController',
        templateUrl: 'Projects/Evaluation/templates/evaluate.html'
    });
    $routeProvider.when("/login", {
        controller: "loginController",
        templateUrl: "login.html"
    });

    $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
});
```

using `location.href = "/#/evaluate"` and `$(location).attr('href', "/#/evaluate")` can route to other page at first click but on the second click with the link will will just loop throughout my controller and get an error..

using `$window.location.href("#/evaluate")` will not route to other template but loop throughout the my controller and again get an error..

using `$("a[href='#/evaluate']").click()` has no response.. no route nor loop

Why I have an error like this in `IE Browser` but when i used `Chrome` or `Firefox` it run so fine using my original code which is `$window.location.href("#/evaluate")`

Is any one have an idea how to route in angularJS regardless what browser the user will use?

Comment: what version of IE??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you please try using the below format (i.e. without "#/")

```
    $location.path('/evaluate');

    or

    $location.path('/evaluate').replace();
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. There is one post and i didnt read his/her name is that you that made the first post..coz he/she got the answer same as you but its my fault i didnt notice the error but anyway thanks again